# Praat latest version

Tags: update-manager

I'm trying to install PraatR but I think something's missing because I don't have the latest version of Praat. Do you know how to update it on ubuntu by terminal? Thanks!!

Comment: How were you installing? What version you got? And which Ubuntu release are you using?

Comment: The repositories are often not the most recent versions of software. If you want the most recent version, install from source.

Answer (score 1):

First, try the following command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
sudo apt-get install <INSERT APPLICATION NAME HERE>
```

And finally, if that doesn't work:

```
sudo apt-get remove <INSERT APPLICATION NAME HERE> && sudo apt-get install <INSERT APPLICATION NAME HERE>
```